# SQL Commandline login error: sp2-0306

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I'm simply trying to logon to a newly installed Oracle Database 11g Express Edition (Windows) using the "Run SQL Command Line" from the start menu.
As specified on [Oracle® Database Express Edition Getting Started Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/admin.112/e18585/toc.htm#XEGSG110), I'm using the following commands:

```
SQL> connect
Enter user-name: system
Enter password: <password-for-system>
```

But the logon fails with the following error:

```
SQL> connect
Enter user-name: system
Enter password:
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Make sure your PASSWORD case matches that of the fixed password!

Comment: Also, please check this--->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550542/sqlplus-login-error-when-using-bash-variables-sp2-0306-invalid-option#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resoved the error.
It was an authentication problem.
But shouldn't the server be more verbose and say invalid uname/password?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with some Oracle versions if the passphrase contains special characters.

Comment: make sure the passwords entered directly on the command line have special characters escaped properly

Answer (score 0):

if the password contains special characters like '@' we need to use "" for the password.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).